# Cyclic dependency between Datas-project and Builders-project

Tags: c#, .net, cyclic-dependency

Here is the code I want to achieve:

> - A `Character` has `strength`, `constitution`, and some other stats.
> - Each `Character` has `BaseStats` depending of his class.
> - Each `Character` has `RandomStats` bonus, with positive values from 0 to 3.
> - A stat may not be lower than 1, nor higher than 10.
> - A `Character` may have `Bonus` and `Malus` in their stats.
> - If a `Character` has 8 in `strength`, plus a bonus of 4, and a malus of 1, he finally has 10 (8+4-1=11 > 10).
> - If a `Character` has 3 in constitution, plus a bonus of 1, and a malus of 4, he finally has 1 (3+1-4=0 < 1).

In my .NET solution, I try to separate the `datas` and `builders` in different projects. Currently, I have something like this in my `datas` project:

```
namespace Data.Entities.Characters
{
    public abstract class Character : Entity
    {
        public abstract EntityStats BaseStats { get; }
        public EntityStats RandomStats { get; }
    }
}

namespace Data.Stats
{
    public struct EntityStats
    {
        private Dictionary<EntityStat, int> _stats;
        public int this[EntityStat stat] { get { return _stats[stat]; } }

        public EntityStats(int strength, int constitution, /* ... */)
        {
            _stats = new Dictionary<EntityStat, int>();
            _stats.Add(EntityStat.Strength, strength);
            _stats.Add(EntityStat.Constitution, constitution);
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have a `builder` which sum a `List<EntityStats`.

```
namespace Builder
{
    public class EntityStatsBuilder
    {
        private List<EntityStats> StatsList { get; set; }
        public EntityStatsBuilder() { StatsList = new List<EntityStats>(); }
        public void Add(EntityStats stats) { StatsList.Add(stats); }

        public EntityStats ToStats()
        {
            int strength = 0,
                constitution = 0, 
                /* ... */;

            foreach (EntityStats stats in StatsList)
            {
                strength += stats[EntityStat.Strength];
                constitution += stats[EntityStat.Constitution];
                /* ... */
            }

            // module FMath =
            //     let Clamp value min max =
            //         if value < min then min elif value > max then max else value
            return new EntityStats(
                FMath.Clamp(strength, 1, 10),
                FMath.Clamp(constitution, 1, 10),
                /* ... */
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the following:

> My `builders` project references my `datas` project.
>   **ERROR**: I want to add a `FinalStats` property in my `Character` class. This `FinalStats` should use my `EntityStatsBuilder` class. Then, my `datas` project should reference my `builders` project.

```
public EntityStats FinalStats
{
    get
    {
        EntityStatsBuilder builder = new EntityStatsBuilder();
        builder.Add(BaseStats);
        builder.Add(RandomStats);
        return builder.ToStats();
    }
}
```

How should I modify my global architecture in order not to have this cyclic-dependency?

Comment: Have you considered using interfaces and putting those in a third shared assembly?

Comment: I don't understand your advice, could you please be more explicit? Thank you

Comment: Right now you have Assambly A with ClassA using ClassB from assembly B which in turn uses ClassA from Assembly A => Cyclic dependency. My usual approach to this is to create interfaces and put them in a shared assembly C, so you have : Assembly C: IntfA, IntfB , Assembly A: ClassA implements IntfA using IntfB, Assembly B: ClassB implements IntfB using IntfA, so Assemblies A and B only depend on Assembly C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the dependency inversion principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Basically create an interface for your `EntityStatsBuilder` and put that in a separate project.
Now both projects can reference that interface project. If you want to follow the Microsoft naming convention, call it `SomethingSomething.Abstractions`.

Now in your startup project using dependency injection, you inject a concrete `EntityStatsBuilder` in your `Character` object. For that you can use either a DI Framework, or simple constructor injection, depending on your need.

Comment: Following the [Implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle#Implementations) section, the interface should be in my `Data` project. What solution should I follow?